# How can I add a button on every line

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and mysql to do a simple shopping cart. I can display the whole database, but how can I add a button on each line; for example, "add to cart"?

```
    <?php

$link = mysqli_connect("rerun","potiro","pcXZb(kL","poti");
if (!$link)
   die("Could not connect to Server");


$query_string = "select * from products";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query_string);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0 ) {
    print "<table border=0>";
    while ( $a_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
         print "<tr>\n";
         foreach ($a_row as $field)
             print "\t<td>$field</td>\n";
         print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column after the $field column and just linked up the **Add to cart** button to your **Add to Cart page** and just put the **product id** so that If you press the **Add to cart button** on that row, the product id on that row will be confirmed and by using this product id you can get the product information in the cart page and confirm the order.

```
if ($num_rows > 0 ) {
    print "<table border=0>";
    while ( $a_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
         print "<tr>\n";
         foreach ($a_row as $field)
             print "\t<td>$field</td>\n";
             print "\t<td><a href='cart.php?id=$your_product_id'>Add to cart</a></td>\n";
         print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a button would be crafted with a combination of HTML and CSS; you merely need to use PHP to `echo` out the code in the loop.

```
while ( $a_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
     print "<tr>\n";
     foreach ($a_row as $field)
         print "\t<td>$field</td>\n";
         print "\t<td><a href='process.php?id=$field'>Add to cart</a></td>\n";
     print "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another column on each row.

```
print "<table border=0>";
while ( $a_row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
     print "<tr>\n";
     foreach ($a_row as $field)
         print "\t<td>$field</td><td><button>Add to cart</button>\n";
     print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In foreach loop added code is

```
    foreach ($a_row as $field)
       print "\t<td>$field</td><td><button>Add to cart</button>\n";//Add button here or any thing you want just add it
  }
```

I hope this is helps you

Thanks